# why lastInsertId is not working, it'll only give an empty value

Tags: php, pdo

```
class Customer extends Dbh {
    protected function setAddCustomer($c_name, $c_address){

      $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('INSERT INTO  customer (c_name, c_address) VALUES (?, ?);');

      if(!$stmt->execute(array($c_name, $c_address))) {
        $stmt = null;
        header("location:../index.php?error=connectionfaild!");
        exit();      
       }

      $last_id = $this->connect()->lastInsertId();
      return $last_id;
      
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776818/pdo-lastinsertid-always-return-0

Comment: The one other problem could be using $pdo->exec($sql) instead of $pdo->query($sql).

exec($sql) will return always 0 when you use $pdo->lastInsertId(). So use query() instead.

Comment: Which database are you using? AFAIK, SQLite doesn't support this functionality for example.

Comment: What does `connect()` do? Are you opening a new connection with `$this->connect()->lastInsertId();`?

Comment: vixducis XAMPP server.

Comment: Álvaro González Yes.It connects with database

Answer (score 0):

You're establishing a new connection every time you interact with database server within the same script. That has two main side effects:

1. You're slightly reducing performance and increasing the DB server resource use.
2. You no longer have access to session-wide features, such as last insert ID or transactions.

The solution is to open one connection and reuse it during script lifetime. You can, for instance, refactor your `connect()` method into a `getConnection()` method like:

```
public function getConnection(): \PDO
{
    if (!$this->connection) {
        $this->connect();
    }
    return $this->connection;
}
```

... or use some kind of dependency injection:

```
public function __construct(\PDO $connection)
{
    $this->connection = $connection;
}
```

If you think about it, it makes sense. A global last inserted ID value wouldn't be particularly useful because concurrent accesses to database server would render it useless for most purposes.